# Как правильно использовать регулярное выражения js?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как из таких данных

```
<option value="645">Євдокимова Анастасія</option>
<option value="649">Іваненко Оксана</option>
```

С помощью регулярного выражения или простого js создать массив типа ключ-значение

```
'645' => 'Євдокимова Анастасія'
'649' => 'Іваненко Оксана'
```

Comment: это просто случайный набор текста или у вас в разметке на странице есть `select` с которого вы и хотите достать данные ?

Comment: мне нужно вытащить эти данные с уже готового сформированого html текста и создать массив

Answer (score 2):

```js
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
 var value = {};
for (var i =0; i<= elem.length-1; i++){
    var key = elem[i].getAttribute('value');
    value[key] =elem[i].innerHTML;
}

console.log(value);
```

```html
<body>
<select>
  <option value='1'>Пункт 1</option>
  <option value='2'>Пункт 2</option>
</select>
</body>
```

Кажется, так :)

Comment: спасибо! Добра Вам

Comment: а если на странице будет больше 1го селекта ?

Comment: jqery мне поможет взять по классу или id )

Comment: ну можно и без `jquery`, + я всеравно делал бы через выбор конкретного селекта вместо выбора сразу опций

Comment: Ребята у меня такая ситуация, что html уже сгенерирован и без value быть не может + я дам id нужному селекту и норм...